# Power BI - Cumulative / Running Average

Tags: powerbi, cumulative-sum

I need to have the "Running average" for the table rows within Power BI. I was able to generate the "Cumulative" Column, but I am not able to make the math work after all.

In the third column, I simply need something like "divide (Cumulative Row) by (running number of rows)"

E.g.:

```
(42 + 44 + 39) / 3
```

or:

```
123 / 3
```

My current code:

```
Average total = 
DIVIDE(
Calculate
([Summe_FeaturesPI12],
Filter(Allselected('ADOPI12_1_Feature Aufteilung'),'ADOPI12_1_Feature Aufteilung'[Current Sprint]<=MAX('ADOPI12_1_Feature Aufteilung'[Current Sprint])),
Filter(Allselected('ADOPI12_1_Feature Aufteilung'),('ADOPI12_1_Feature Aufteilung'[State] in {"Done/Cancelled"})
))
, COUNTROWS('ADOPI12_1_Feature Aufteilung')
)
```

Power BI Table:

[image: Power BI Table]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got some help from a colleague. The solution of my problem lies in the second half. For anyone who should need it, please take a look on the solution:

```
Running Average = 
DIVIDE(
Calculate
([Summe_FeaturesPI12],
Filter(Allselected('ADOPI12_1_Feature Aufteilung'),'ADOPI12_1_Feature Aufteilung'[Current Sprint]<=MAX              ('ADOPI12_1_Feature Aufteilung'[Current Sprint])),
Filter(Allselected('ADOPI12_1_Feature Aufteilung'),('ADOPI12_1_Feature Aufteilung'[State] in {"Done/Cancelled"})
))
, 
CALCULATE
    (DISTINCTCOUNT('ADOPI12_1_Feature Aufteilung'[Current Sprint]),
    Filter(Allselected('ADOPI12_1_Feature Aufteilung'),'ADOPI12_1_Feature Aufteilung'[Current Sprint]<=MAX              ('ADOPI12_1_Feature Aufteilung'[Current Sprint]))
    )
)
```